# When I paste a string into Xcode I always get an error and have to re-type it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, syntax-error

This happens every time I paste a line of code containing a string into Xcode. for example when I pasted this into Xcode:

```
simonLabel.text = @"Good Job!";
```

I received an error saying that there was an "unexpeceted '@' in program"

If I delete everything and retype exactly the way I pasted it I do not get an error.

Comment: From where did you copy the original string? Looks like mismatch in implementation of '@' in both systems..

Comment: Sometimes I've noticed the "Just In Time" error checking magic in Xcode 4 throws slightly false warnings/errors. Do you get an error when you do the real compile & build *after* you do the pasting?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra is correct, this is issue of just copy-paste, the character copied is not proper.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I copied it from a Safari Tech Books Online tutorial.
I've tried deleting just the '@' character and retyping it, but it seems that I need to delete almost the entire line of code in order for the debugger to accept it.

Comment: try to just delete the space before the '@' and retype it, I had such problems of copy paste from the Apple documentation before where a space wasn't a normal space but "unbreakable space"

Comment: @MichaelDautermann thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately when I tried compiling the program, after pasting the snippet of code, the error was not resolved.

Comment: I Still can't seem to find any solution other than deleting the entire line and re-typing it.

Comment: So far my current solution is to paste into vim fix up the invisible characters + other things, then copy & paste back into xcode. There should be a better way in xcode, or atleast make such characters more visible / easier to be manipulated with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many problems that can appear there:

1. `"` can be a different character that you expect
2. (space) can be a different character that you expect
3. invisible characters. Something you won't see in the editor at all but they got there with the copy-paste.

All these problems can happen because

1. You copy it from a website with different encoding (or from a really badly writter website)
2. You copy it from a smart editor (e.g. MS Word, Open Office) which replaces some of the characters to match locale (e.g. quotation marks) or replaces/add spaces based on grammar and word wrapping (e.g non-breaking space).

Comment: Great explanation thanks. I would never have considered invisible characters. Good to keep in mind. Thanks!